# Assigning a Unique ID to each Unique Name in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of 20+ names in column A. There are some duplicates names in this list.

What I would like to do is assign a number to each of the unique name in the list. If a duplicate name occurs, the number should be duplicated as well.

Here's an example of what I am hoping to do:

```
Name    ID
Alex    1
Allen   2
Bret    3
Dan     4
Dave    5
Dave    5
Harry   6
Joe     7
Joe     7
Tom     8
```

As you can see, a unique number is assigned to each of the name. Where a duplicate name appears, the original number gets duplicated as well, such as in the case of Dave and Joe.

If possible, I would like to avoid using VBA.

This list is dynamic and changes frequently, so I can't hardcode these numbers to each of the names, which is why I am hoping to get some assistance in developing a formula.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: Do the numbers have to be sequential or is unique sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in B2 and fill down.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, A$1:B1, 2, FALSE), SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A$2:A2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this data starts with a header in `A1`:

In `B2` put a `1` for your first unique id, then in `B3` place the formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3, $A$2:$B2, 2, FALSE), B2+1)
```

And copy that down

Comment: ... as long as the Name data is sorted or grouped. If Harry was between the two Dave's then the first Joe would duplicate Harry's ID. Maybe MAX+1 instead of B2+1.

Comment: Max+1 seems reasonable. Or sort the list first. I was just assuming they were sequential based on OP's sample data. :/